# MVVM Company -> Categories associations in checklistbox

Tags: wpf, silverlight, data-binding, mvvm, binding

I have a Silverlight application using MVVM.

My application has "Companies", each company can be associated to multiple "CompanyCategories"

So in my ViewModel a Company has :

```
public ObservableCollection<CompanyCategories> Categories {get;set;}
```

The Categories list is configurable in another part of the application, so it is dynamic.

**What I want to do :** 
In my CompanyView, I want to associate Categories to my Company.

So every available Categories 
should be in a CheckListBox and only the ones associated to my Company should be checked.  When the user checks/uncheck a category from the list I want to add/remove it from Company.Categories[]

How can I do that with Bindings, DataContexts, ItemsSource

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell; your CheckBoxList's ItemsSource property should bind to the list of all Possible categories. The IsChecked property of each item in the checkbox list should bind to a property which returns a function result that checks whether the Category is in the Company's Categories collection. The Categories ObservableCollection's CollectionChangedEvent should trigger the PropertyChanged event of the aforementioned property that returns the function result.

Is that enough to get you started?